# Is there an option to see STDOUT with docker SDK when building images?

Tags: python, docker, docker-image

I just started building my docker images with python instead of sh-scripts, but am confused as I am getting no STDOUT with my script.

Is there a way to enable it? The parameter "quiet" seems to enable/disable if an object is returned.

Thank you,

Jakob

Minimal example:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
```

```
# main.py
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
client.images.build(path='.')
```

Where executin the build command in console yields:

```
jakob@jakob:~/foo$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  20.99kB
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu
---> 7e0aa2d69a15
Successfully built 7e0aa2d69a15
```

executing the python file yields nothing. I would love for both to be similar in their STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

I never use this before but I simply put `build()` in `print()` and I found it returns some values.

```
(<Image: 'ubuntu:latest'>, <itertools._tee object at 0x7f836bea2b00>)
```

So I start testing it with `print(...)`, `print(type(...))`, `print(dir(...))`

Because I saw word `itertools` so I tried to use it with `for`-loop.

This code

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
result = client.images.build(path='.', quiet=False)

#print(result)

print(result[0], type(result[0]))
print(dir(result[0])

for item in result[1]:
    print(item)
```

gives me

```
<Image: 'ubuntu:latest'> <class 'docker.models.images.Image'> 

['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'attrs', 'client', 'collection', 'history', 'id', 'id_attribute', 'labels', 'reload', 'save', 'short_id', 'tag', 'tags']

{'stream': 'Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu'}
{'stream': '\n'}
{'stream': ' ---> 7e0aa2d69a15\n'}
{'aux': {'ID': 'sha256:7e0aa2d69a153215c790488ed1fcec162015e973e49962d438e18249d16fa9bd'}}
{'stream': 'Successfully built 7e0aa2d69a15\n'}
```

It shows dictionares so using `key,value` I can format it (and filter it)

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
result = client.images.build(path='.')#, quiet=False)

#print(result)

#print(result[0], type(result[0]))
#print(dir(result[0]))

for item in result[1]:
    #print(item)
    for key, value in item.items():
        #print(key, ':', value)
        if key == 'stream':
            text = value.strip()
            if text:
                print(text)
```

and this gives me

```
Step 1/1 : FROM ubuntu
---> 7e0aa2d69a15
Successfully built 7e0aa2d69a15
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It does answer my question - It felt weired when i am building multiple docker-images (each taking up to 1h+) to not get any feedback or beeing able to check the build process. Even though i would expect the package to be able to print those kinds of things in some way. Thank you